# Alternative Firefox add-on to Form History Control

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there another plug-in I can use instead of [Form History Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12021/)?

Sometimes it just doesn't work and I'd like to find a replacement or another plug-in which does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

[Sxipper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4865/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

[iMacros for Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) lets you record whatever you enter in a form and replay it.

There is also an addon for IE and Chrome, so you can fill out forms in any of these browsers.